# Accessing list of projects from accounts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Below is the code which gives me list of accounts.

```
<% @accounts.each do |account| %>
  <li><%= link_to account.name %></li>
<% end %>
```

How to access the list of projects of my specific account.

Comment: try account.projects inside your loop

Comment: @Mandeep: you mean something like this <li><%= link_to account.projects %></li>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<% @accounts.each do |account| %>
  <li><%= link_to account.name %></li>
  <li><%= link_to account.projects %></li>  #this will give you a collection of projects associated with that account
<% end %>
```

If you want a link_to for each individual project then you'll have to use another loop like this:

```
<% @accounts.each do |account| %>
  <li><%= link_to account.name %></li>
  <% account.projects.each do |project| %>
    <li><%= link_to project %></li>  #this will give you individual project associated with that account
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Edit:

Incase you **don't have any projects for an account** you can do:

```
<% @accounts.each do |account| %>
  <li><%= link_to account.name %></li>
  <% if account.projects %>
    <% account.projects.each do |project| %>
      <li><%= link_to project %></li>  #this will give you individual project associated with that account
    <% end %>
  <% else %>  # add this else block to execute your code when there are on projects 
    <p> No projects associated with your account</p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Why am i getting undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass on the account.projects?

Comment: @theJava it's giving you error because you don't have projects for that account. updated my answer in case there are no projects